# matlab low priority system call

Tags: windows, matlab

I want to check/improve some correction algorithm I use.

The whole thing is implemented in Matlab and goes something like this

```
for ii = 1:nn
   ... % Prepare some input files
   parfor i = 1:n
      system('...'); % simulation code
   end
   ... % Use the output and prepare some stuff that can be used to prep the next iteration
end
```

Wherey n is a bigger number than the #Treads I can use. This normaly takes a while to run and in the meantime I would like to use the computer for other (non cpu hungry) tasks. Therefore I would like to run the system calls with low priority.

I already tried to do this using  new or start but then the call doesn't wait till it's finished and just proceeds. There would be a dirty hack over checking if the output files exist, but then again I was asking myself if there was not a better solution for that...

Any help would be greatly appreciated

yours
magu_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the `/wait` flag in `start` command:

```
>> system( 'start /LOW /WAIT matlab.exe' );
```

started a new matlab instance and resumed execution only after I closed the opened application.

Of course, you need to replace `matlab.exe` in my proposed solution with the simulation program name you want to run.

Comment: Works like a charm thx. I also added the /MIN flag for convinience.

Comment: Great answer! Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I'm using STDOUT from the .exe I'm calling and for some reason, STDOUT doesn't work when using the Windows start command. Any other methods?